# Can't Change URL in WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i'm trying to change a url from a webview when I receive an action, which in handled by the method below. The method works, but the webview url is never changed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myWebView.delegate = self;
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://cardapiomestre.com.br/beta";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

The method:

```
-(void) setWebViewURL:(NSString*)url
{
    NSString *urlAddress = url;
    NSURL *essaUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:essaUrl];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

The url from setWebViewURL param it's a valid URL. I even tried to set the url manually but it didn't work.

I call it on AppDelegate.m:

```
ViewController* myScript = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[myScript setWebViewURL:@"http://google.com"];
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying this on device ? Put a breakpoint on delegate methods and see if the new load request getting fired or not.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Works only on viewDidLoad. Not by my method.

Comment: Are you calling your method on viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No. On app delegate, when I receive notifications.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I just updated the question.

Comment: I see. [[ViewController alloc] init]; is the issue. YOu are just creating a new instance, by this way ,the webview will be nil.

Comment: YOu should post a notification in this place , and listen to this notification in your view controller

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I tried to implement didReceiveRemoteNotification on ViewController, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the appDelegate, instead of doing:

```
ViewController* myScript = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[myScript setWebViewURL:@"http://google.com"];
```

Here you are creating a new instance of your view controller and by this way your webView will be nil, hence you are not seeing the expected result.

You should post a notification in app delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshWebView" object:nil];
```

and in your viewController, listen to this notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadWebView) name:@"refreshWebView" object:nil];
```

and in your view controller, define method:

```
-(void)reloadWebView{
    NSString *urlAddress = @"your-url";
    NSURL *essaUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:essaUrl];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Also, I just had to pass a notification object with the info I need.